# Ошибка работы с памятью

Tags: c++

Есть массив структур:

```
struct structCell
{  
    void * ptrData; //Указатель на данные в ячейке  
    unsigned char TypeOfCell; //Тип данных хранимых в ячейке  
};
structCell *arrStruct=new structCell [1000];
```

В цикле `arrStruct[0..999]` указатель `ptrData=(void * )new long`, либо `ptrData=new (void * )double[10]`, перед удалением массива структур `(delete[] arrStruct)`, освобождаю память в цикле `delete ptrData`, либо `delete[] ptrData` в зависимости от типа `TypeOfCell`. Но выскакивает ошибка: `_BLOC_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHEAD->nBlockUse)`. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А зачем вы вообще такое делаете? Почему не сделать нормально классы с деструктором и с нормально типизорованным указателем внутри, как в C++ принято? Для начала, это design faul, а уже потом ошибка управления памятью.

Comment: То то и оно! Сначала я использовал класс а не структуру, в деструкторе делал delete (в зависимости от того что хранит ptrData вызывал delete либо delete[]) Такая же ошибка, вот и не знаю где собака порылась! (Клас имитирует работу ячейки Excell которая может хранить три типа данных - long, double, char*)

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть текст, а не намёки на текст. По крайней мере строка `structCell arrStruct = new`... - уже бяка. Да и `delete` для `void *` не определён. (1) Какой транслятор (ежели не секрет) (2)

Comment: Строку structCell *arrStruct=new structCell [1000]; подправил, на форуме забыл поставить (*) Вот в void* и вопрос! Просто одним типом указателя я пользуюсь что бы хранить разные типы данных в конкретном экземпляре структуры! А пользуюсь C++ VS2010

Comment: Используйте шаблоны. Используйте классы. А я подумаю как бы нарисовать красивый пример.<p>
PS: а голый void* - зло.

Comment: Как там в анекдоте "Ну кошмар. Но ведь не кошмар, кошмар, кошмар". А насчет `void *`, так всё равно надо делать upcast, тем более, что значение `TypeOfCell` есть. `switch (TypeOfCell) {case LONG: delete (long *)ptrData...`

Comment: @alexiz прав. Код в студию.

Мне кажется проблема где-то в циклах с new и delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
structCell *arrStruct=new structCell [1000];
```

после этой строки я бы еще проинициализировал память:

```
memset((void*)arrStruct, 0, sizeof(structCell)*1000);
```

В этом случае легко обнаружить клетки, в которых есть данные и удалить их...
Надеюсь, это поможет

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html) или boost::variant. Про отличия можно почитать [тут](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any)

Answer (score 0):

Ну тогда давайте начнём с анализа моего класса!

```
#define TOC_String  1//Тип ячейки - строковый
#define TOC_Double  2//Тип ячейки - вещественный типа Double
#define TOC_Long    3//Тип ячейки - целого типа Long
#define TOC_NULL    0//Тип ячейки - пустая

class CellofTab
{
public:
        CellofTab();
        ~CellofTab();
        void * ptrData;//Указатель на данные в ячейке
        unsigned char TypeOfCell;//Тип данных хранимых в ячейке     
};

CellofTab::CellofTab()
{
    ptrData=(void*)NULL;
    TypeOfCell=TOC_NULL;
}
CellofTab::~CellofTab()
{
    switch (TypeOfCell)
    {
    case TOC_String:
        {
            delete[] (char*)ptrData;
            break;
        }
    case TOC_Double:
        {
            delete (double*)ptrData;
            break;
        }
    case TOC_Long:
        {
            delete (long*)ptrData;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `void * ptrData` в public'е фигово. Лучше сделайте ф-ции GetLongData, GetStringData, GetDoubleData и т.д. И парные им SetLongData, SetStringData... которые будут выделять память под ячейку <p>
Дефайны плохо - лучше enum.<p>
`ptrData=(void*)NULL;` - не рассказывали, что в конструкторе можно сразу инитить переменные-члены? Так:
`CellofTab::CellofTab() : ptrData(NULL),TypeOfCell(NULL) {};`

Comment: Ну можно и функции (GetLongData, GetStringData, GetDoubleData), но ведь всё равно нужно будет использовать указатель void либо обьявлять 3 типизированых указателя, а не хотелось бы! Колличество ячеек может быть и 10 000 000 штук!

Comment: <i>3 типизированых указателя</i>. Я и не предлагаю. Хорошо - пускай будет один void*. Но все равно я бы его упрятал подальше внутрь программы.

Comment: Ну это же просто хороший стиль, а не решение вопроса с ошибкой!?

Comment: Возможно, что если переписать по-человечески, то ошибка уйдет. Например, Вы случайно где-то переписали память перед указателем. Или за указателем и при delete удаляется чего-то не то.

Comment: Ну для трёх типизированных указателей есть `union`. Правда смысл это имело бы при разной длине указателей. Ну и эстеты могли бы порадоваться отсутствием `cast`ов, поскольку возможная ошибка была бы спрятана в `union`.

Answer (score 0):

Для case TOC_String: просто delete (char *)ptrData;

И я бы еще добавил после switch() {  ... } TypeOfCell=TOC_NULL;

Comment: delete (char *)ptrData - почему без[]? Там же массив символов!?

Comment: Да это по большому счету без разницы. В ptrData помещается просто адрес (указатель на байты), выделяемые оператором new. Сколько выделить байт зависит от sizeof для выражения в new.

Покажите код заполняющий/освобождающий элементы массива.

Comment: Нет, не без разницы.
Если использовался new[], то нужно высвобождать память с помощью delete[]. Если 'обычный' new, то - 'обычным' delete. Иначе можно словить странные ошибки.

Comment: ptrCell[InsPosition].ptrData=new unsigned char[st];  
CopyMemory((unsigned char*)(ptrCell[InsPosition].ptrData),ptrString,(st)*sizeof(unsigned char));

Comment: Вопрос в сторону: а вот эти вот страсти - они в конструкторе или в тексте основной программы?.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, в конце концов ошибку практически нашёл! Привожу аналог моего кода который выполняется не правильно!!!

```
class MyClass
{
public:
        long *ptr;
        MyClass():ptr(0){};
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClass *A,*B;
    A=new MyClass;
    (*A).ptr=new long[10];
    B=new MyClass;
    (*B).ptr=new long[10];
    *B=*A;
    delete A;
    *A=*B;
    return 0;
}
```

После удаления (delete A;) также нарушается содержимое B! Почему!?

Comment: Потому что компилятор неявно генерирует код оператора присваивания. Который почленно присваивает каждый элемент А каждому элементу В. Решение: самому определить оператор прмсваивания. А заодно конструкторы класса.
А еще *А=*B после удаления А - белиберда.